# How do I connect my custom auth script to ejabberd?

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-api, ejabberd-auth

I have searched everywhere that I can think of for this.  I know how to create my custom auth script (I am using Python) but I just can't figure out how to connect it to the ejabberd server.  Does it have to be in a special location?  Special name?  Do I point to it from ejabberd.yml in some way?

What triggers ejabberd to call my script instead of its own internal auth code?

Answer (score 0):

In ejabberd.yml tell that you want to use external as authentication method, and also provide the full path to your script, see
https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#external-script